# screen doesn't run a bash file

Tags: linux

I have a "restart" file:

```
pkill screen
screen -dmLS a bash run.sh
screen -dmLS b bash b/run.sh
```

both the files do same thing:

run.sh:

```
screen -dmLS secA python run.py
```

b/run.sh:

```
screen -dmLS secB python bRun.py
```

("bRun.py" is stored in "b" folder: "b/bRun.py")

When I run the restart file, only the first file works correctly.
The second file does not run the "secB" file.
What I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I guess the first command doesn't terminate and thus the second does not get started.  Did you try to put `echo foo > /tmp/foo` in between the two calls to see if this line is reached at all?

Comment: That's not the problem - "b" screen is running, but "secB" isn't.  @Alfe